# why , if the insertion point of a search is at element 2, the actual insertion point returned will be -3?

Tags: java

i did not understand this point in in `Collection` 
"Unsuccessful searches return an int index that represents the insertion point.
The insertion point is the place in the collection/array where the element
would be inserted to keep the collection/array properly sorted. Because positive return values and 0 indicate successful searches, the `binarySearch()`
method uses negative numbers to indicate insertion points. Since **0 is a valid
result for a successful search, the first available insertion point is -1. Therefore,
the actual insertion point is represented as (-(insertion point) -1). For
instance, if the insertion point of a search is at element 2, the actual insertion
point returned will be -3.**"

Comment: This is most likely gonna get closed, unless you ask a proper question, with relevant code snippet & the exact the problem!

Comment: If the insertion point of a search is at element 2, what do you think the method should return?

Comment: I'm confused... you answered your own question in the question. What don't you understand about the quote?

Comment: @roliu ... (-(insertion point) -1) , by this the answer is : -3 but why

Comment: @jlordo , if insertion point in 2 then it would be 1 !

Comment: @user2301409: look closely `( MINUS (insertion_point) MINUS 1)` calculates to -3 for `insertion_point` 2.

Comment: I assume you don't understand why the insertion point is -3 rather than -2 for insertion at 2? It's like this: -1 represents the 0 insertion point, therefore, all subsequently larger insertion points will likewise be one larger than their actual insertion point.

Comment: @R.J , please think .... if you have a entry point 2 then why insertion point in -3 why { 1 0 -1 -2 } are left !

Comment: @RayStojonic ... is it acting like binary search tree !

Comment: I don't know what that has to do with anything. As the docs say: 0 is a valid result for a search - that means 0 cannot also be used to tell you that "it wasn't found, but hey, if it was here, it would be at 0",  so they had to use -1 to communicate to the programmer that the insertion point is 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the api uses the range [0, intinity) to represent a FOUND result - so returning 0 means it actually found what youre looking for in index 0 (1st index of the collection/array).

that means that the range available for returning NOT_FOUND results is negative - (-inf, -1]

so how do you communicate, under this constraint, the result "requested element wasnt found, but should be inserted at index 0" ?

you cannot return -0, as that is the same as +0 and would indicate a FOUND result. so you add an offset to you negative number. that way "should have been at index 0" becomes -1, "should have been at index 1" becomes -2 etc.